# Adding a node to a linked list

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function that gets the head of the linked list , the tail of the linked list, the place to add the node (n), number and a price.

Each node in the linked list contains a number which is also the place of the node in the list.
Something here dosen't work, it keeps placing the new node in the first postion of the linked list for some reason. Thank's for the help.
Here is a photo of how it spots to print:

[image]

```
void AddNewItem(PItem *head, PItem *tail, int n, int a, float b){
    PItem temp = *head, curr = *head;
    temp->num = a;
    temp->price = b;
    temp = (PItem*)malloc(sizeof(PItem));

    while (n < temp->num) {
        temp = temp->next;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    temp->next = curr->next;
    curr->next = temp;
}
```

Here is the struct:

```
typedef struct Item
{
    int num;
    float price;
    struct Item* next;
}*PItem;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185765/discussion-on-question-by-elad-kobi-adding-a-node-to-a-linked-list).

Comment: You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). (hint: No) There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 0):

The following proposed code:

1. eliminates unused parameters
2. cleanly compiles
3. performs the desired operation
4. properly checks for errors

And now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// format struct definition for readability 
// and eliminate undesireable 'typedef' of a pointer
struct Item 
{ 
    int num; 
    float price; 
    struct Item* next; 
};


// use meaningful names for paramters and
// allow for this might be first entry into linked list
void AddNewItem(struct Item **head, int num, float price)
{
    struct Item *curr = *head;
    struct Item *prev = *head;

    struct Item *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Item));
    if( !newNode )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    // initialize fields of new node
    newNode->num = num;
    newNode->price = price;  
    newNode->next = NULL;

    // check if first node added to linked list
    if( !*curr )
    { // then first addition to linked list
        *curr = newNode;
    }

    else
    {
        // check for end of linked list and
        // check for found desired position in linked list
        while ( curr->next )  
        {
            if( curr->num >= newNode->num )
            {
                break;
            }

            // implied else

            prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
        }

        // insert the new item into the linked list
        newNode->next = curr;
        prev->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: in the function signature the parameter `struct node **head` means the call to the function used: &head`  Otherwise the function cannot change where the `head` of the linked list points.

Comment: `if( !*curr )` is a mistake

Comment: @grapes,  so what would be the correct statement?  Note: I was trying to check if the head pointer, back in the caller is still NULL because no nodes have been added to the linked list  Perhaps it should be: `if( !(*curr) )`

Answer (score 0):

@user3629249 It's Elad Kobi.Thanks for the help.
When I try to debug your code, I get a few errors.
Another thing, you did not use the parameters tail and n. 
The parameter n represents the position of the node I want to add.

Comment: Your posted code did not use `tail` so since that made it an unused parameter, I did not mention it in my answer.  It was TOTALLY not clear that you wanted to order the list via the value in `n`. So I did not use it.  However, you could use `n` rather than `num` (another strong case for using meaningful variable and parameter names).  BTW: you answer is not an answer to the question,  Much better to have commented on my answer